# Configure Eclipse to add a comment header the top of new modules

Tags: java, eclipse, code-templates

How can Eclipse be configured to automatically add a comment header to the top of new classes that are created in a project?

```
/*
*  Name
*  Date of creation
*  etc.
*/
```

Comment: "new module" == "new class"?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Yes, if I am adding that kind of file to a project.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in Java a `class` is not a `module`: [7. Packages and Modules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-7.html), and [7.7. Module Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.7)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger, that's interesting. I did not know Java formally defined the term 'module' . I was using module in a broader sense meaning any source code file. Then I looked at the question tags added by user7294900 and I saw that 'java' is there, which I never intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit in Preferences:  Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates

Choose Comments -> Files -> Edit:

[image]